# Sorting by date field across sections not working

Tags: templating, entries, datetime, sort

I've seen a number of answers prescribing how to sort across different sections...but I'm not seeing it work. Here's what I've tried:

```
{% set profileIds = craft.entries.section('profiles').order('profileBorn asc').ids() %}
{% set eventIds = craft.entries.section('events').order('eventDate asc').ids() %}
{% set timelineIds = profileIds|merge(eventIds) %}
{% set timeline = craft.entries.id(timelineIds) %}
```

Or:

```
{% set timeline = craft.entries.section(['profiles','events']).order('GREATEST(eventDate, profileBorn) desc') %}
```

Then for either, I'm doing:

```
{% for entry in timeline %}
```

In both cases, I get entries in the following order, with their `{{ entry.profileBorn }}` or `{{ entry.eventDate }}` shown here:

- 1832-02-01 / events entry
- 1830-01-01 / profiles entry
- 1840-01-01 / profiles entry

Any thoughts? Thanks!

UPDATE:

This looks like the SQL being generated by the first answer's suggestion, which is still outputting the event entry first.

`` SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`type`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_i18n`.`slug`, `elements_i18n`.`uri`, `elements_i18n`.`enabled` AS `localeEnabled`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `content`.`title`, `content`.`field_profileBio`, `content`.`field_body`, `content`.`field_profileBorn`, `content`.`field_copyright`, `content`.`field_datePrecision`, `content`.`field_datePrecisionBorn`, `content`.`field_datePrecisionDied`, `content`.`field_profileDied`, `content`.`field_eventDate`, `content`.`field_mediaCaption`, `content`.`field_mediaPublicationDate`, `content`.`field_mediaSource`, `content`.`field_mediaTitle`, `content`.`field_siteTitle`, `entries`.`sectionId`, `entries`.`typeId`, `entries`.`authorId`, `entries`.`postDate`, `entries`.`expiryDate`, `structureelements`.`root`, `structureelements`.`lft`, `structureelements`.`rgt`, `structureelements`.`level`
FROM `craft_elements` `elements`
JOIN `craft_elements_i18n` `elements_i18n` ON elements_i18n.elementId = elements.id
JOIN `craft_content` `content` ON content.elementId = elements.id
JOIN `craft_entries` `entries` ON entries.id = elements.id
JOIN `craft_sections` `sections` ON sections.id = entries.sectionId
LEFT JOIN `craft_structures` `structures` ON structures.id = sections.structureId
LEFT JOIN `craft_structureelements` `structureelements` ON (structureelements.structureId = structures.id) AND (structureelements.elementId = entries.id)
WHERE (((((elements_i18n.locale = :locale) AND (content.locale = :locale)) AND ((elements.id=:elementsid1) OR (elements.id=:elementsid2) OR (elements.id=:elementsid3))) AND (elements.archived = 0)) AND ((elements.enabled = 1) AND (elements_i18n.enabled = 1) AND (entries.postDate <= '2017-07-12 12:47:25') AND ((entries.expiryDate is null) OR (entries.expiryDate > '2017-07-12 12:47:25')))) AND (elements_i18n.enabled = 1)
GROUP BY `elements`.`id`
ORDER BY GREATEST(field_eventDate, field_profileBorn) asc LIMIT 100 ``

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is sound. I don’t really have an idea why it doesn’t work, but I bet it has to do with the SQL that is caused by setting the `section` param to an array.

What I would try next is the following, kind of a merge of your ideas.

```
{% set profileIds = craft.entries.section('profiles').limit(null).ids() %}
{% set eventIds = craft.entries.section('events').limit(null).ids() %}

{% set idParam = profileIds|merge(eventIds) %}

{% set timeline = craft.entries({
    id: idParam,
    order: 'GREATEST(eventDate, profileBorn) desc',
}) %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Same thing happens with the code you provided.

Comment: I pasted in the SQL being generated there.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t really have an idea why that happens.